# Data Annotation for virtual member?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am designing a sort of logging system where each item in the log is accompanied by the user that logged it. The `user` class uses `Data Annotations` to modify its display name. When displaying `User.Name` in one of my `log` views, I wish to show a different display name.

**Classes**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {set;get;}
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string Name{set;get;}
}

public class Log
{
    public int LogID {set;get;}
    public int UserID {set;get;}

    public virtual User User{set;get;}
}
```

If I were to use the following code in my view, the text shown is "User Name". Is there way to make the `DisplayName` "Assignee" using `Data Annotations`, or do I need to this manually?

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem when you have view data attached to the model (the display name): Sometimes you need different labels depending the view.

In your case the answer is no, you need to change the label manually.

Or, you will need to create a specific viewModel for your view:

```
public class LogViewModel
{
    public int LogID {set;get;}
    public int UserID {set;get;}

    [Display(Name = "Assignee")]
    public string UserName {set;get;}
}
```

Comment: Eduardo, is there really a [DisplayName()] annotation? If so, do you need to download a particular annotation NuGet package?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni The previous syntax, `[DisplayName("SomeName")]` is correct. It is a part of `System.ComponentModel`